# UINavigationBar changing default font colors

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, hook

I'm trying to write a mobile substrate tweak to modify the default font color used by application in UINavigationBar title and buttons,
e.g. Instead of default white Title in the Navbar all white navbar text would turn to red,

Hope that is making sense.

At the moment I'm trying:

```
%hood UINavigationBar
-(void)setTitleView:(id)arg1 {
    %orig
    UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor]
}
%end
```

I feel its because I'm trying to set a new UILabel rather than replacing the default setTitleView that is pulled.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS 5+ there is a new way to do this using the [UIAppearance](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol. There's a good tutorial about how to use it [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4344/user-interface-customization-in-ios-5).

If you need to support iOS 4 still, you can create a subclass of `UIViewController` and override the various `init*` methods to set properties when the class is created or in `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear` etc.. All your controllers can then inherit from this instead of `UIViewController` directly.

There are other ways to do this such as adding category methods on `UIViewController` or swizzling its methods - but I think the above is the simplest.

Comment: So am i right in saying, that in viewDidLoad method I need to override it calling setTitleView method of NavigationBar, and instead point it to (e.g.)
  `[[UINavigationBar appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
   UITextAttributeColor,
   [UIColorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:1.0]];`

If i wanted to make the titleText black

Comment: You just need to set the `appearance` attributes once when the app starts, before any views appear. Creating your own superclass for view controllers is not necessary if you're using the iOS 5 `UIAppearance` class.